# How to update Gradle installation to latest release?

Tags: gradle

I am trying to initialize a Java application via Gradle Build Init Plugin, with command [`gradle init --type java-application`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_init_plugin.html#sec:javaapplication_), but I am getting the following error:

> The requested build setup type 'java-application' is not supported. 
>   Supported types: 'basic', 'groovy-library', 'java-library', 'pom', 'scala-library'.

I have the version 3.1 of Gradle (which does not include `java-application` type).

So, I was wondering how can I update Gradle local installation, without having to remove it, download it and install it again?

Comment: > remove it, download it and install it again You have to do exactly this. Or just install another version alongside it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html), which is the preferred way of starting a Gradle build. Follow these steps to use the right version of Gradle:

1. Run `gradle wrapper --gradle-version 3.3` to install the right version of Wrapper into your project folder.
2. Henceforward use `gradlew` instead of `gradle`. The former uses your Gradle project installation (i.e. version 3.3), whereas the latter uses your computer home directory installation (i.e. version 3.1).
3. Running `gradlew -v`  returns `Gradle 3.3` and `gradle -v` returns `Gradle 3.1` in your case.
4. Now, run `gradlew init --type java-application` to setup a command-line application.